# Find values in list which sum to a given value

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I'm trying to code up something simple and pythonic to identify combinations of values from a list which sum to a defined value, within some tolerance.

For example:

if `A=[0.4,2,3,1.4,2.6,6.3]` and the target value is `5 +/- 0.5`, then the output I want is `(2,3), (1.4,2.6), (2,2.6), (0.4,2,3), (0.4,3,1.4)` etc. if no combinations are found then the function should return 0 or none or something similar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's  a NP-Complete problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: if you can solve this in polynomial time with 100% correctness, let me know ;) we can become bro :D

Comment: Let's see, this is [approximation algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm)

Comment: I was asked almost same question in an interview. I didn't know the answer :(

Comment: @hyades blimey! That's a difficult interview question!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a recursive approach:

```
# V is the target value, t is the tolerance
# A is the list of values
# B is the subset of A that is still below V-t
def combination_in_range(V, t, A, B=[]):
    for i,a in enumerate(A):
        if a > V+t:    # B+[a] is too large
            continue

        # B+[a] can still be a possible list
        B.append(a)

        if a >= V-t:   # Found a set that works
            print B

        # recursively try with a reduced V
        # and a shortened list A
        combination_in_range(V-a, t, A[i+1:], B)

        B.pop()        # drop [a] from possible list

A=[0.4, 2, 3, 1.4, 2.6, 6.3]
combination_in_range(5, 0.5, A)
```

Comment: Great answer. Little typo on the last line, it should call `combination_in_range` instead of `re`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I had updated the code with better names and comments, and missed that last line.  It's fixed now.

Comment: How can i use this to return all the values?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `itertools.combinations`

```
def first_attempt(A=A):
        for i in xrange(1,len(A)+1):
                print [comb 
                                for comb in list(itertools.combinations(A,i)) 
                                if 4.5 < sum(map(float, comb)) < 5.5
                                ]
## -- End pasted text --

In [1861]: %timeit first_attempt
10000000 loops, best of 3: 29.4 ns per loop
```

Output -

```
In [1890]: first_attempt(A=A)
[]
[(2, 3), (2, 2.6)]
[(0.4, 2, 3), (0.4, 2, 2.6), (0.4, 3, 1.4)]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Haha, not fast enough... ;) (exponential time algorithms via bruteforce)

Comment: You can reduce the list with values > 4.5: `A = filter(lambda x: x < 4.5, A)`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer towards itertools.combinations and the example code. I'll definitely check it out. Speed wise, I'm only likely to have 50 ish values in the list and most will definitely not sum ie be way above the tolerance

Comment: @Mark 2^n algorithm. So wont be scaling too well

Comment: @Tiger-222 That would remove these guys - (0.4,2,3). No ?

Comment: @fixxxer No, but I did a mistake, it is 5.5, not 4.5. It will return `[0.4, 2, 3, 1.4, 2.6]`.

Comment: @Mark hopefully all numbers are positive??

Comment: @hyades yes all numbers are positive

Comment: @Mark: 50-ish is still going to take forever with this solution. You're at least going to want to use branch-and-bound to cut off all supersets of too-expensive subsets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is branch-and-bound? The real data spans 0-2000 ish in terms of values with 50-100 data points in each set, vaguely equally spaced, so the number that will sum within a tight tolerance should be small. But I realise that it may take a lot of checking to get to the end even if only a few sum

Comment: @Mark: [Branch-and-bound is a means of solving problems like these by exploring a tree of decisions you could make and cutting off the search any time the decisions you've made obviously can't be extended to a valid solution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) Here, each node would be a decision whether or not to include a certain data point, and you'd backtrack whenever the nodes you've included have too high a sum or the nodes you've excluded prevent you from reaching the minimum valid sum.

Comment: My answer with a recursive algorithm uses branch-and-bound to find viable branches

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll definitely try the recursive algorithm