# Find values in list which sum - optimisation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, optimization

This is really a follow on from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130890/find-values-in-list-which-sum-to-a-given-value) I asked earlier this year. I received a great answer to the following problem:

> I'm trying to code up something simple and pythonic to identify
>   combinations of values from a list which sum to a defined value,
>   within some tolerance.
>
> For example:
>
> if A=[0.4,2,3,1.4,2.6,6.3] and the target value is 5 +/- 0.5, then the
>   output I want is (2,3), (1.4,2.6), (2,2.6), (0.4,2,3), (0.4,3,1.4)
>   etc. if no combinations are found then the function should return 0 or
>   none or something similar.

I implemented the suggestion in my code. However, the method (see below) has quickly become the performance limiting step in my code. It's fairly quick to run each iteration but it is being run many, many times.

Therefore, I'm turning this out to the community (who are far brighter than I am) for your help. Can you see anyway to optimise this function or replace it with something much faster?

```
def findSum(self, dataArray, target, tolerance=0.5):
    for i in xrange(1, len(dataArray)+1):

        results = [list(comb) for comb in list(itertools.combinations(dataArray, i)) 
                   if target-tolerance < sum(map(float, comb)) < target+tolerance]

        if len(results) != 0:
            return results
```

Comment: [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)  would be a better place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to be the [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

According to wikipedia, if all your elements in A are positives, and you search for an approximate result, then this algorithm:

```
initialize a list S to contain one element 0.
for each i from 1 to N do
   let T be a list consisting of xi + y, for all y in S
   let U be the union of T and S
   sort U
   make S empty 
   let y be the smallest element of U 
   add y to S 
   for each element z of U in increasing order do
      //trim the list by eliminating numbers close to one another
      //and throw out elements greater than s
      if y + cs/N < z ≤ s, set y = z and add z to S 
if S contains a number between (1 − c)s and s, output yes, otherwise no
```

should give you your answer. It has a polynomial complexity.

in pseudo python(sorry i havent wrote python in a while)

```
def calc(A,s,c):
'''
 A is the list containing yours numbers
 s is your goal value
 c is your approximation ie +/- 0.5
'''
    S = [0]
    y = 0
    for i in xrange(1,N):
        T = [x+y  for x in A for y in S]
        U = list(set(T) | set(S))
        U.sort()
        S = []
        y = min(U)
        S = [y]
        for z in U:
            if y + cs/N < z ≤ s:
                y = z 
                S.append(z)
    return [ x for x in S , x>s-c , x<s+c ]
```

Comment: N is the number of decision variable, as i understand it, its the number of element in the list you try to sum. (The A list in the python-pseudocode)

Comment: cs i'm not too sure, i did copy it too quickly, i didnt notice. I guess it could be c*s (with c a small constant > 0 and s your goal value) ? I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

I provided the answer with the recursive function in your previous question and made some optimizations to it for this answer.  Not only is it faster than using `itertools.combinations()`, it returns the correct answer.

```
import itertools
import timeit

def findSum(dataArray, target, tolerance=0.5):
    for i in xrange(1, len(dataArray)+1):

        results = [list(comb) for comb in list(itertools.combinations(dataArray, i))
                   if target-tolerance <= sum(map(float, comb)) <= target+tolerance]

        if len(results) != 0:
            return results

def recursive(dataArray, target, tolerance=0.5, i=0, possible=[]):
    results = []
    max_target = target + tolerance
    min_target = target - tolerance
    l = len(dataArray)
    while i < l:
        a = dataArray[i]
        i += 1
        if a > max_target:    # possible+[a] is too large
            break
        if a >= min_target:   # Found a set that works
            results.append(possible+[a])
        # recursively try with a shortened list dataArray and a reduced target
        result = recursive(dataArray, target-a, tolerance, i, possible+[a])
        if result:  results += result
    return results

dataArray = [0.4,2,3,1.4,2.6,6.3]
dataArray.sort()
target = 5

print findSum(dataArray, target)
print recursive(dataArray, target)

print timeit.Timer(lambda: findSum(dataArray, target)).timeit(number=100000)
print timeit.Timer(lambda: recursive(dataArray, target)).timeit(number=100000)
```

As you can see in the output, your function returns only two results but the recursive function returns all five results.  For 100000 iterations, your function takes about 2 seconds and the recursive function takes about 1.85 seconds.

```
[[2, 2.6], [2, 3]]
[[0.4, 1.4, 3], [0.4, 2, 2.6], [0.4, 2, 3], [2, 2.6], [2, 3]]
2.03791809082
1.84496808052
```

Depending on the data, the recursive function could be even faster because it exits a loop when the sorted data can no longer fit the target range.  This requires that `dataArray` is sorted before you call the function.