# Generating all possible combinations inefficient

Tags: python

Code to generate all possible combinations of a list of numbers and fetch combinations  with a particular sum:

```
combos = []

for each in combinations_with_replacement(list, number):
    if sum(list(map(int, each))) == particular_number:
        combos.append(list(map(int, each)))
```

the code is working perfectly fine. But the problem is if the number argument in the function **combinations_with_replacement** is more than 8 it is taking a lot of time. Is there a optimized way my logic can be replaced with?

Comment: Well for one thing you could do `list(map(int, each))` once and assign it to a variable rather than as part of the if statement and inside it

Comment: please provide a full minimal example. Thanks

Comment: Yes, there are much more efficient ways to do this. Perhaps start by working through the problem yourself on paper (with a small `number`) and see what algorithm *you* follow. I've seen this as an interview question, so you'll probably also be able to find solutions on the web.

Comment: @Uriel I assume it's from [**`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

Comment: @PeterWood my bad.

Comment: `sum(list(map(int, each)))` can be `sum(int(value) for value in each)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find values in list which sum to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130890/find-values-in-list-which-sum-to-a-given-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, quit repeating work.

- Convert the list elements to integers before you enter the loop.
- The combination is already in a tuple; do you really need to convert it to a list for `combos`?
- Instead of generating all combinations for a variety of list lengths, try the recursive solution you can find with a "sum to target" search.  This will *greatly* reduce the quantity of lists to try.

The basic idea of the recursive solution is:

```
# Given: remaining target sum and list of numbers (lon) to use
if target = 0:
    return []
if target < 0 or len(lon) == 0:
    return None

if target >= lon[0]:
    # add one of the first number; recur
    result = sum_to_target(target - lon[0], lon)
    return result + [lon[0]] if result else None

# Done with this number; try the rest of the list
result = sum_to_target(target, lon[1:])
return result if result else None
```

Try every step both with and without the first number of the list.
If you exceed the target or run out of numbers, you fail.
If you hit the target exactly, you succeed: build the valid set of numbers as you crawl back up the call stack.

Note that I've left the problem of concatenating all solutions as an exercise for you ... as well as some debugging and boundary details.